# Adding space to an array

Tags: arrays, logic

Good day,

I have a photo gallery that pulls from a json feed.  The json gallery contains 600 photos, but I am pushing out 10 at a time, with the gallery reloading on the tenth feed.

Now I have two arrays.
PhotoList.length - carries a count of how many photos are in the feed
currentPhotoIndex. - It holds the index or place of the images.

The problem:  currentPhotoIndex only shows 10 indexs no matter what.  When I reload more data from the feed it overwrites the old data, keeping the index the same.

How to I add more index space to an array?  I am thinking I can do an append to currentPhotoIndex, but how?

I need something like, currentPhotoIndex = currentPhotoIndex + 10;  (this by the way gives me a current index of 20 instead of creating 10 empty spaces.)

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use an array list.

[Here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=234) is a java code example to show the basics of how it works.

If it is not what you had in mind, try this:

Step1: Create an array of size 10, when it is full make a temporary array of array.size*2.

Step2: Now add the contents of the first array to the temp array.

Step3: Re-initialize the array with a new size (temp array size).

Step4: Now add the contents of the temp array to the resized array.

Step5: Repeat from step 1 as many times as neaded

Here is an example in java:

```
String array[] = new String[10];
//add items to array
String tempArray[] = new String[array.length*2];
tempArray = array;
array = new String[tempArray.length];
//add more items to the array
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better not to make 2 new arrays?
`String[] tempArray = array;  array = new String[array.length*2]`?